# ASP.net chart refreshing page

Tags: asp.net

I realized that the asp:chart controler was refreshing the page.

For example if I click on a button to display a chart, the current page is refreshed, but I don't want it to be.

Let's say I want to diplay two charts. I have the following code in my default.aspx file (code generated with the toolbox):

```
    <div>
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
        <series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1">
            </asp:Series>
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server">
        <series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1">
            </asp:Series>
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
    </div>
```

And the behindcode in the default.aspx.cs file:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] yValues = { 71.15, 23.19, 5.66 };
        string[] xValues = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] yValues = { 71.15, 23.19, 5.66 };
        string[] xValues = { "DDD", "EEE", "FFF" };
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
    }
```

My problem is that when I click on the Button1, my first chart appears. But then when I click on the Button2, the first chart disappear and the second one appears.

I would like to keep both charts displayed!

Is it possible? How?

Comment: A good start would be posting some of your code, so we can have an idea?

Comment: Here you go, I edited to add code

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 buttons on the page, each one firing its own click event. This way, of course you will see just one chart a time.

If you want to see both all the time, do it like this (both buttons pointing to a shared event handler):

```
<div>
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1">
        </asp:Series>
    </series>
    <chartareas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </chartareas>
</asp:Chart>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="ChartButtons_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>
<div>
<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server">
    <series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1">
        </asp:Series>
    </series>
    <chartareas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </chartareas>
</asp:Chart>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="ChartButtons_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

On your CS file:

```
protected void ChartButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] yValues = { 71.15, 23.19, 5.66 };
    string[] xValues = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

    yValues = { 71.15, 23.19, 5.66 };
    xValues = { "DDD", "EEE", "FFF" };
    Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
}
```

Comment: Yes it will work for this example. But my real problem is that I don't want the page to be refreshed when I display a chart.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna check this out

Comment: It's fairly easy. You'll see. Any problems, just complement your question and we are here to give you a hand.